# Managed Wifi API examples

Tags: c#, winforms, wifi

Are there any good examples of using [Managed Wifi API?](https://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) for windows forms

I've already coded some using it based on what i've found but I want to see a working example that displays a list of available connections and then choose one to connect to. Is there other things I can try to do that?

So far here's what i've done but i'm not even sure yet if it works because i'm on a computer with no wireless network card

```
//display connections on a listview
lstNetworks.Items.Clear();
WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
{
   Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
   foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
   {
      Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = network.dot11Ssid;
      string networkName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
      ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(networkName);
      item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString());
      item.SubItems.Add(network.wlanSignalQuality + "%");
      lstNetworks.Items.Add(item);
   }
 }

// Click on a listview row displays the connection details on labels

//connecting to a network

WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
{
  string profileName = label1.Text;
  string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><name>{0}</name></SSID><nonBroadcast>false</nonBroadcast></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><connectionMode>manual</connectionMode><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>none</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName);
  wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
  wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
}
```

If anyone can comment on the xml profile that would be great, i will be connecting to networks with no password.